# Battery status working in the background

Tags: android, android-service-binding

I am working on a Project, where the Application sends notification for every battery percentage change.I will get the notification only when the application is in foreground.When I put it in background I won t get any notification.Here is the code. what modifications do I need to do,so that I will get the notification even when my application is in the background.

> **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textview;
    IntentFilter intentfilter;
    int deviceStatus;
    String currentBatteryStatus="Battery Info";
    int batteryLevel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBatteryStatus);
        intentfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(broadcastreceiver,intentfilter);
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            deviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,-1);
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            int batteryLevel=(int)(((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f);

            if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING){

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Charging at "+batteryLevel+" %");
                //Notifying Operation..

            }

            if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING){

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Discharging at "+batteryLevel+" %");
                //Notifying Operation..

            }

            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+"= Battery Full at "+batteryLevel+" %");
                //Notifying Operation..

            }

            if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN){

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Unknown at "+batteryLevel+" %");
                //Notifying Operation..
            }


            if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING){

                textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Not Charging at "+batteryLevel+" %");
                //Notifying Operation..

            }

        }
    };
}
```

> **Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vinayts.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I have made Manifest edited as below but then also its showing error where i am declaring the manifest with the inner class with $ symbol**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
 Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bledemo.android.bluetoothlegatt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- Min/target SDK versions (<uses-sdk>) managed by build.gradle -->


    <!--
    Declare this required feature if you want to make the app available to BLE-capable
    devices only.  If you want to make your app available to devices that don't support BLE,
    you should omit this in the manifest.  Instead, determine BLE capability by using
    PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)
    -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity
            android:name="com.bledemo.android.bluetoothlegatt.DeviceScanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.bledemo.android.bluetoothlegatt.DeviceControlActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.bledemo.android.bluetoothlegatt.BluetoothLeService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.bledemo.android.bluetoothlegatt.SettingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.bledemo.android.bluetoothlegatt.MainActivity$broadcastreceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you really sure that you wanna get a notification every time your battery level changes?

Comment: Yes, I am calling one method which executes notification.inside the if condition in broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

To receive battery level changes even while your app isn't running, you should register your broadcastreceiver in your manifest to listen for both events by defining the ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED within an intent filter:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You will need to make your BroadcastReceiver publicly accessible, then update the location in your receiver android:name in the manifest file.

Find more details here:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: i am trying to register the Receiever in the manifest but its showing error.is it possible to register the receiever when we are using it as annonymous inner class

Comment: Yes it's possible. The receiver `android:name` attribute should look like `.path.to.class.MyClass$MyInnerClass`

Comment: You cannot register receivers in the manifest for most implicit broadcasts on Android 8 and newer [due to background execution limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts).